# How would I prevent a domino-like STOPPED tasks effect and is it a good idea?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

When I launch a AWS ECS Task Definition revision using `ecs-cli compose --file <...> --project-name <...> --aws-profile <...> service up --create-log-groups --cluster <...> --launch-type FARGATE --region eu-west-1` some of the tasks go from a `PENDING` to a `RUNNING` state. The issue is that if one container goes into a `STOPPED` state, the rest appears to automatically go into a similar `STOPPED` state. Is there a way to prevent this and only have the specific containers crash independently, or is that an "anti pattern"?

Having all containers crash simultaneously makes debugging more difficult.

Here is the Dockerfile provided for `ecs-cli compose service up`:

```
services:
  ...-file-api:
    environment:
      ...     
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-file-api
    ports:
      - 3054:3054
    restart: always
  ...-frontend:
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-frontend
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
  ...-help-api:
    environment:
      ...
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-help-api
    ports:
      - 3059:3059
    restart: always
  ...-login-api:
    environment:
      ...
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-login-api
    ports:
      - 3055:3055
    restart: always
  ...-login-frontend:
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-login-frontend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
  ...-mail-api:
    environment:
      ...
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-mail-api
    ports:
      - 3063:3063
    restart: always
  ...-main-api:
    environment:
      ...
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-main-api
    ports:
      - 3053:3053
    restart: always
  ...-mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.20-xenial
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-mongo
    restart: always
  ...-plan-api:
    environment:
      ...
    image: ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-plan-api
    ports:
      - 3058:3058
    restart: always
  ...-redis:
    image: redis:4.0.14-alpine
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: /ecs/log
        awslogs-region: eu-west-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ...-redis
    restart: always
version: '3'
```

As an example "crash", the `...-main-api` service gets a `Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED` which is visible under `CloudWatch -> Logs -> Insights`. Logs for e.g. `...-mongo` - another service - is not available yet it still settles for the `STOPPED` state.

Expected: The remaining containers should not go into an immediate `STOPPED` state as a result of one or more other containers stopping. They should only go into a `STOPPED` state if they crash independently.

Currently: All containers apparently stop regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a parameter called `essential` as `false` in the task definition and that should do it.

**[Task Definition Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment)** :

> essential
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Required: no
>
> If the essential parameter of a container is marked as true, and that container fails or stops for any reason, all other containers that are part of the task are stopped. If the essential parameter of a container is marked as false, then its failure does not affect the rest of the containers in a task. If this parameter is omitted, a container is assumed to be essential.
>
> All tasks must have at least one essential container. If you have an application that is composed of multiple containers, you should group containers that are used for a common purpose into components, and separate the different components into multiple task definitions. For more information, see Application Architecture.
>
> "essential": true|false